# How do I create an object that will start a thread that will run alongside my program?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I've been trying to work out how to create a Timer class that will count in milliseconds when you create a new object of that class.

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {
private long ms;

public Timer() {
    this.ms = 0;
    new Thread(this).run();
}

public Timer(long ms) {
    this.ms = ms;
    new Thread(this).run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        ms++;
        Time.sleep(1);
    }
}

public long getElapsed() {
    return ms;
}
}
```

This is my Timer class, however, when I try to make an object of it:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
```

it gets stuck on the thread within the timer. I simply don't understand how I'm supposed to have a thread run continuously alongside my main program.

It should also be noted that I'm using this as an example as there are most likely better ways of creating a timer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Thread t = new Thread(new Timer());` and then `t.start();` Though I would really recommend `System.currentTimeMillis()` as it seems to provide exactly what you need without the hassle of threads.

Comment: You seem to expect that `Thread.sleep(1)` will sleep for exactly 1 ms, and you're ignoring the time it takes to execute any other part of the code.  Synchronization issues aside, `ms` will very soon have no relationship whatsoever to the actual elapsed time.  Explain what you're actually trying to accomplish, and maybe we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: I wanted to use it so that #getElapsed() could be used to get the time elapsed from when I had made the object. But the issue seems to stem from the fact that it doesn't leave the while loop and the whole program focuses on that instead.

Comment: run() doesn't start a thread. start() starts a thread. To get the number of elapsed milliseconds since the object was constructed, just initialize ms to System.currentTimeMillis() in the constructor, and do `System.currentTimeMillis() - ms`. But why would you need a thread to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you really want what you are trying to do here because this would waste a lot of CPU time for nothing.

Why don't you try something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private long birthTime;

    public MyObject() {
        this.birthTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public long getElapsedMilliseconds() {
        return (System.nanoTime() - this.birthTime) / (1000 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1337);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("obj is " + obj.getElapsedMilliseconds() + "ms old");
}
```

And will return:

> `obj is 1337ms old`

You only need to store the current time in milliseconds from that moment you create `MyObject` and then you can deduce the actual time your object is living/has lived by subtracting again the current time in milliseconds.

Comment: To compute elapsed time, use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  The latter is not *monotonic*; it can change non-linearly if the system time is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new Thread(this).run()
```

use

```
new Thread(this).start()
```

But as Stefan Falk said, it would be better store the `System.currentTimeMillis()` and use it to calculate the "live time" of your object.